# Arduino #define gives incorrect values for multiplication

Tags: arduino

I am somewhat confused with why the code below gives an incorrect value for x and y. When I run it on my Arduino b is shown to be 124, as one would expect, however x is shown to be 10420 and y is 2104.

I believe it is due to the "#define" command as if I replace the define for b with an "int" x and y return the correct values. Oddly this issue only occurs for multiplication and division, addition and subtraction using values from "#define" function correctly.

```
#define a 20
#define b a + 104
int x = b*100;
int y = 100*b;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
Serial.println(b);
Serial.println(x);
Serial.println(y);
delay (500);
}
```

Please could someone explain why the multiplication returns incorrect values and why the order of multiplication impacts the result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Arduino is not C!

Comment: @Olaf This has nothing arduino specific in it, it is entirely to do with C preprocessor behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

define not calculates the value, it is pre-compile directive - so you get following result before compile:

```
#define a 20
#define b a + 104
int x = 20 + 104*100; //b*100
int y = 100*20 + 104; //100*b;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
Serial.println(b);
Serial.println(x);
Serial.println(y);
delay (500);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C preprocessor macros are based on token substitution, not evaluation. The first rule when using them is to add extra parentheses. The zeroth rule is not to use them for simple constants.

So either write with parenthesis:

```
#define a 20
#define b (a + 104)
int x = b*100;
int y = 100*b;
```

which expands to

```
int x = (20 + 104)*100;
int y = 100*(20 + 104);
```

or use constant variables for constants

```
const int a = 20;
const int b = a + 104;
int x = b*100;
int y = 100*b;
```

which avoids the problem. The compiler should optimise the constant away.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how macro arguments are expanded. They are expanded verbatim, so in your case `a + 104` is substituted where `b`  appears like  this

```
int x = a + 104*100;
```

which is then expanded to

```
int x = 20 + 104*100;
```

would this give the result you get?